# IndexError: list index out of range for loop in python

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

Hi Everone I Want To **Scrape** But u get this error while in 59

i have 1089 items in my `xlsx` file

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\seleniuminform.py", line 28, in <module>
    s.write(phone[i].text + "," + wevsite_link[i].text + "\n")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


with open("Sans Fransico.csv","r") as s:
    s.read()

df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx') # Get all the urls from the excel
mylist = df['Urls'].tolist() #urls is the column name

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for url in mylist:

    driver.get(url)
    wevsite_link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+ .link-size--default__373c0__1skgq")

    phone = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+ .text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_")

    num_page_items = len(phone)
    with open("Sans Fransico.csv", 'a',encoding="utf-8") as s:

        for i in range(num_page_items):
            s.write(phone[i].text + "," + wevsite_link[i].text + "\n")

driver.close()
print ("Done")
```

Link:

https://www.yelp.com/biz/daeho-kalbijjim-and-beef-soup-san-francisco-9?osq=Restaurants

Here Error in This **Website and Phone**:

[image]

Comment: Evidently, `wevsite_link` is not as long as `phone` is. Can you explain why you expect it to be the same length? Have you considered what you want to happen if it isn't?

Comment: you should first find all `.text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+` and then use for loop to search phone and webside in every `.text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+` to create pair `(phone, webside)`. And sometimes you may get `(None, webside)` if some `.text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+` doesn't have `phone`

Comment: Can You Please Answer So I Can Understand Better!

Comment: you shows image with webside and phone but some items on page may not have phone - and you may get less phones than websites.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel explained it well, that’s basically what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: So did @furas actually

Comment: @KarlKnechtel So What i need to do?

Comment: First, you need to *think about the data and your requirements* until you can answer the questions I asked you. I can't solve the problem for you because I do not know what you want to happen in every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some items have no phone so it found less phones then websides.

You should rather first find all `".text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+"` and later use `for`-loop to search `phone` and `website` in every item separatelly.

Using `try/except` you can recognize if item has no phone and use empty string as phone number

```
for url in mylist:

    driver.get(url)

    all_items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+")

    for item in all_items:
        try:
            wevsite_link = item.find_element_by_css_selector(".link-size--default__373c0__1skgq")
            wevsite_link = wevsite_link.text
        #except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        except:
            wevsite_link = ''

        try:
            phone = item.find_element_by_css_selector(".text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_")
            phone = phone.text
        #except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        except:
            phone = ''

        with open("Sans Fransico.csv", 'a',encoding="utf-8") as s:
             s.write(phone + "," + wevsite_link + "\n")
```

---

I didn't have url to page so I couldn't test it.

Comment: One Last Thing i get this error while running your code?

Comment: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified in line 20

Answer (score 2):

I’m not very familiar with Selenium, so i can’t comment on that aspect.

The first time you open “Sans Francisco.csv” you read the contents without assigning them to a variable.

As for your error, it’s caused by the fact that your range is based on the length of `phone`, *not* on the length of `wevsite_link`. If `wevsite_link` is shorter than `phone`, you get an error. In simple terms, you are finding fewer website links than phone numbers, yet your code assumes that you will always find the exact same amount of each.

Can you explain your code a bit more? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What Code You Need?

Comment: @UsmanShahzad I meant an explanation of what you want your code to do. What’s the context?

Comment: i want to scrap phone and website'

Comment: Question  Updated Check!

Comment: Please Check Question Updated

Comment: But The Website is longer than phone you can see in image

Comment: @UsmanShahzad I’m pretty sure the length of the url vs the length of the phone isn’t the problem. It’s about the number of urls you find vs the number of phone numbers you find.

Comment: Sorry I Think @furas Solve My Problem

Comment: @UsmanShahzad Alright, do you now understand why you were having that problem?

Comment: Yes! I Understand

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, I'm suspecting that

```
phone = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+ .text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_")
```

is returning 0. Perhaps the css selectors you're trying to find matches for aren't accurate.

Comment: That shouldn’t cause an error though, no? His range is based on the length of `phone`, so he won’t be indexing outside of it.